# Loop to check if directories exist

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I am  a newbie trying to populate a Months drop-down based on whether the directories exists for the particular month.

I know the directories names will be Jan 2010, Feb 2010, Mar 2015 and so on...

I am currently using...

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\Jan\\"))
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Jan 2015");
}
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\Feb\\"))
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Feb 2015");  
}
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\March\\"))
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("March 2015");
}
```

How can I make this easier? I just want to loop through and if directory exists add particular name to the drop-down.

Comment: Have you *tried* to implement it with a loop?

Comment: Create a string array with the name of the months(or whatever the folder names are) then just loop through the array and concat each entry at the before the last slash

Comment: Are the directories named "Jan" and "Feb" or "Jan 2010" and "Feb 2010"?  You say they are the latter, but your code is looking for the former.

Comment: If you would use `Mar` instead of `March` you could use `Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i =>DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i))` to get all possible names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your months in a list and iterate over it:

```
List<string> months = new List<string>()
{
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};

foreach (string month in months)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\" + month))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(month + " 2015");
    }
}
```

Or if you like Linq:

```
foreach (string mounth in mounths.Where(mounth => System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\" + mounth)))
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(mounth + " 2015");
}
```

---

If you want some automatic stuff:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // <== Or any culture you like
List<string> monthNames = new List<string>(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames);
foreach (string month in months)
{
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Desktop\\Month\\" + month))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(month + " 2015");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `March` instead of `Mar`, otherwise you don't have to create the list manually: `var allMonthNames = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i)).ToList();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, we can create it from `Date`, I'll add it, but I prefer to let the OP do the choice

Comment: Great - the first option worked just had to change the if(System.IO.File.Exist.... to if(System.IO.Directory.Exists... Thanks for your help I couldn't think of the condition to use for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach on this one:

```
string src = @"C:\Desktop\Month\";            
string[] values = { "Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(src).Where(d => months.Contains(d.Replace(src, ""))).Select(d => d.Replace(src, "")));
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to my mind is that you can use something like this

```
    List<String> wehaveadd = new List<String>();
    wehaveadd.Add("Jan");
    wehaveadd.Add("Feb"); // do all the months

   foreach(var item in wehaveadd){
     var path = "C:\\Desktop\\Month\\" + item;
     if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
     {
      DropDownList1.Items.Add(item + " 2015");
     }
   }
```

Comment: It appears that all the directories are at the same level, so there's no need for recursion.

Comment: You should remove that comment about "making recursive directory call" since you're just looping on a list.

Comment: Needs to be `item + " 2015"` in the `Add` call